# filtering a txt file in python on three letter words only

Tags: python-3.x, filtering

I need to write a program in Python3 that can filter a txt file in the Linux shell on three letter words only.

This is what I've got so far:

```
def main(): 
    string = open("verhaaltje.txt", "r")
    words = [word for word in string.split() if len(word)==3]
    file.close()


    print (str(words))

main()
```

Is there anyone that can help?

Comment: `string.read().split() `?

Comment: instead of the string.split() you mean? It doesn;t work... gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

Upload your txt file contents and error logs.

```
string = open("verhaaltje.txt", "r")
words = [word for word in string.read().split() if len(word)==3]
string.close()

print (str(words))
```

With my above code and some text from the internet, I got

```
['the', 'the', 'the', 'm).', 'the', 'the', 'The', 'its', 'ago', 'was', 'm),', 'but', 'now', 'm).', 'and', 'its', 'big', 'but', 'the', 'are', 'and', 'its', 'the', 'and', 'for']
```

---

For the new line, modify a bit of the print statement.

```
print ('\n'.join(words))
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. The only problem I've got now is that it's printed as a list. I'd like to know how to print the three letter words per line. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: import sys

    def main(): 
     for line in sys.stdin:
      line = line.rstrip()
      word = line.rsplit()
      punctuation_marks = ".,!?" + '"'
      for char in line:
       if char in line punctuation_marks:
        line = line.replace(char, " ")
      for word in line:
       if len(word) == 3:
        three_letter_words = word + line
    
      print(three_letter_words)
  
    main()

This is what it should look like, but it gives me an error about this line:  if char in line punctuation_marks:

Comment: I modified my answer.